# How to replace outliers with average

Tags: r

My question is about replacing all the "True" in the column with average.
I have identified the outliers as followed:

```
high <- mean(df$variable1) + sd(df$variable1) * 3
low <- mean(df$variable1) - sd(df$variable1) * 3
df$Outlier <- (df$variable1 < low | df$variable1 > high)
```

So the result is a column with some "True" and "False"
And I want to replace all the "True" with the average of the rest of the data points.

What should I do :)?

Comment: Although I personally do not like to replace outliers with the mean, you could use the `dplyr` package to simply put a conditional mutate df <- df %>% mutate(variable1 = ifelse(Outlier, #mean value, variable1). You can even make this more generic for multiple variables but we would need an example dataframe for tthat.

Comment: Aggreed with Annet, you should just filter out your outlier otherwise the mean will change when adding back the outliers. For example here the mean increase from 5.5 to 6.2 : `df <- c(1:10, 100);
df1 <- c(1:10, mean(df));
mean(df[-11]); 
mean(df1)`

Answer (score 1):

To compute the mean without outlier:

```
avg = mean(df$Variable1[!df$outlier])
```

and then replace only outliers:

```
df$Variable1[df$outlier] = avg
```

Or, in one line:

```
df$Variable1[df$outlier] = mean(df$Variable1[-df$outlier])
```

(although replacing outliers by the average value really sounds like a thing to not do for me)

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions about dealing with outliers? should I replace it with the median or just delete it?

Comment: Start with a proper outlier check (so not a simple mean +/- sd *3, that aint do it), that should give you an indication whether it is actually an outlier and how to deal with it.

Comment: That's quite a complicated question without the context. I guess it depends on what you want to do with your dataset. But I'd agree with Annet, that this rule of sd*3 is quite an approximation.